# Creating an object in javascript that can be target to droppable from jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am trying to drag and drop  elements into a dropbox which is created via javascript. I want to display a message whenever i drop it in one of the blue dropboxes. Sadly, it doesn't work on the new object. If I create a canvas in html-code, it does work. 
Thank you for your help!

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk8sLn9e/

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="outerContainer">
        <div class="tile">Price</div>
        <div class="tile">Shares Outstanding</div>
        <div class="tile">Market Cap</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tile').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        stack: ".tile",
        start: function (event, ui) { createDropBox() },
        stop: function (event, ui) { deleteDropBox() }
    });

    $('.dropContainer').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {alert("alarm")}
    });
})

var dropBoxWidth = 200;
var dropBox1Height = 75;
var dropBoxHeight = 150;

var dropBox1X = 240;
var dropBox1Y = 10;
var dropBox2X = dropBox1X;
var dropBox2Y = dropBox1Y + dropBox1Height + 50;
var dropBox3X = dropBox1X + dropBoxWidth + 100;
var dropBox3Y = dropBox1Y;

function createDropBox() {
    drawRectangle(dropBox1X, dropBox1Y, dropBoxWidth, dropBox1Height, "dropBox1");
    drawRectangle(dropBox2X, dropBox2Y, dropBoxWidth, dropBoxHeight, "dropBox2");
    drawRectangle(dropBox3X, dropBox3Y, dropBoxWidth, dropBoxHeight, "dropBox3");
}

function drawRectangle(left, top, width, height, id) {
    var dropBox = document.createElement("canvas");
    dropBox.style.position = "absolute";
    dropBox.style.left = left + "px";
    dropBox.style.top = top + "px";
    dropBox.style.width = width + "px";
    dropBox.style.height = height + "px";
    dropBox.style.backgroundColor = "#d8ecf3";
    dropBox.style.border = "solid lightblue";
    dropBox.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    dropBox.id = id;
    dropBox.className = "dropContainer";
    document.body.appendChild(dropBox);
}

function deleteDropBox() {
    var element1 = document.getElementById("dropBox1");
    var element2 = document.getElementById("dropBox2");
    var element3 = document.getElementById("dropBox3");
    element1.parentNode.removeChild(element1);
    element2.parentNode.removeChild(element2);
    element3.parentNode.removeChild(element3);
}
```

Comment: When adding elements dynamically, you will want to initialize draggable and droppable after they are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following code:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var boxes = [{
      id: "dropBox1",
      class: "dropContainer",
      props: {
        top: 10,
        left: 240,
        width: 200,
        height: 75
      }
    },
    {
      id: "dropBox2",
      class: "dropContainer",
      props: {
        top: 225,
        left: 240,
        width: 200,
        height: 150
      }
    }, {
      id: "dropBox3",
      class: "dropContainer",
      props: {
        top: 10,
        left: 440,
        width: 200,
        height: 150
      }
    }
  ];

  function drawRectangle(l, t, w, h, id, cn) {
    $("<div>", {
        id: id,
        class: cn
      })
      .css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: t + "px",
        left: l + "px",
        width: w + "px",
        height: h + "px",
        "background-color": "#D8ECF3",
        border: "10px solid lightblue"
      })
      .appendTo("body");
  }

  function makeDropTarget($t) {
    $t.droppable({
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("DROP:", ui.draggable.text(), "ON:", $(this).attr("id"));
      }
    });
  }

  function createDropBoxes(d) {
    $.each(d, function(k, box) {
      console.log("Create Rect:", box);
      drawRectangle(box.props.left, box.props.top, box.props.width, box.props.height, box.id, box.class);
      makeDropTarget($("#" + box.id));
    });
  }

  function deleteDropBoxes(d) {
    $.each(d, function(k, box) {
      $("#" + box.id).remove();
    });
  }

  $('.tile').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    stack: ".tile",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      createDropBoxes(boxes);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      deleteDropBoxes(boxes);
    }
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wLrj3k08/

I would advise staying with either all native JavaScript or all jQuery. It becomes easier when you don't mix up the two in your code.

I would also advise containing all your box data in an Array of Objects. Makes it easier to iterate and store etc. It does not need to be as complex, yet this just makes it a bit easier to work with in my opinion.

Making good use of functions can help a lot. I like to trey and keep them simple so that they are easy to use in a lot of situations. So we have:

- `drawRectangle(l, t, w, h, id, cn)` - makes and appends the `<div>` with the given properties
- `makeDropTarget($t)` - using jQuery Object as a Target, make the target droppable
- `createDropBoxes(d)` - create en mass a number of drop boxes based on specific box data (Array of Objects)
- `deleteDropBoxes(d)` - delete en mass a number of drop boxes based on specific data (Array of Objects)

You may want to make a create and delete function for a single target, yet you can use this to do that too:

```
deleteDropBoxes([{id: "dropBox1"}]);
```

This would work to delete one of the drop targets by ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked! Greatly appreciate your overall feedback!